# MVC: Set value in autocomplete on Edit

Tags: model-view-controller, autocomplete, model, edit

In our MVC application we use jQuery autocomplete control on several pages.  This works fine on `Create`, but I can't make it work on `Edit`.

Effectively, I don't know how to make the autocomplete controls preload the data from model and still behave as an autocomplete in case the user wants to change the value.

Also how can I make sure that the value is displayed in the same format that is used in `Create` calls?

All our autocomplete controls have corresponding controllers and all parse Json results.

Comment: What do you mean by preload and still behave as an autocomplete? Do you want the textbox to contain a value sent to the view by the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Let's Try this! Alright Do this:
Suppose you had a list of countries you needed to filter
Auto Complete knows how to some default things by default but suppose you really wanted CountryName and also you know every keypress does an ajax call to the URL you specify. 
Create an action method like so:

```
  public ActionResult LookupCountry(string q, int limit)
  {
      var list = GetListOfCountries(q, 0, limit);
      var data = from s in list select new {s.CountryName};
      return Json(data);
  }
```

Here is the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#txtCountryName').autocomplete('<%=Url.Action("LookupCountry", "MyController") %>', {
      dataType: 'json',
      parse: function(data) {
          var rows = new Array();
          for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
              rows[i] = { data:data[i], value:data[i].CountryName,          result:data[i].CountryName};
          }
          return rows;
      },
      formatItem: function(row, i, n) {
          return row.CountryName;
      },
      width: 300,
      mustMatch: true,
  });
});
```

Here is the Html

```
<html><head></head><body>@Html.TextBox("txtCountryName",Model.CountryName)</body></html>
```

Basically, The magic is in the call to LookUpCountry
The GetCountriesList(string query, int startindex, int limit)
Returns `MyCountries.Where(c => c.CountryName.SubString(startindex, limit).Contains(query)).ToList();`

So you are making your own trimming function because JQuery has no idea what CountryName is or how to trim it. How ever if it was a javascript object I am not quite sure but do

```
var jsonString = @Html.GetListOfCountries() //Or Model.Countries.ToJSONString()  
var json = JSON.stringify(jsonString); //also JSON.Parse(jsonString) if stringify won't work
```

which would return the necessary countries as a Html Helper Extension method. And perhaps as a list of javascript objects it would be smart enough to handle it that way in it's native language. However the first approach works for me.